# Maximum principle for heat equation, low regularity case

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

I meant to assign to my class the following homework problem:

> If $u\in C^2((0,T)\times \Omega) \cap C^0([0,T]\times\bar{\Omega})$ where $\Omega$ is an open, bounded domain, is such that $\partial_t u - \triangle u \leq - \epsilon < 0$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, then $u$ cannot have a local maximum on the set $(0,T)\times \Omega$.

This follows from simple second derivative considerations. I made a typo, however, and asked my students to prove that

> ... $u$ cannot have a local maximum on the set $(0,T\color{red}{]} \times \Omega$.

**Question**: Is the version with the typo still true? Or is there a counterexample?

**Remark**: If we assume that $\nabla u$ and $\nabla^2 u$ (the spatial gradient and Hessian) both extend continuously to $\{T\} \times \Omega$, then the second derivative test argument also goes through. So any potential counterexample must be non-regular at time $T$.

**Remark 2**: the potential lack of regularity also means we cannot directly apply the mean value integral (e.g. that which is given in Evans' textbook).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This version is still true: if $u$ had a local maximum at $(x,\,T)$, say with $u(x,\,T) = 0$, then $u \leq 0$ in a small parabolic cylinder centered at $(x,\,T)$. After rescaling we can assume that $u \leq 0$ in $\overline{B_1} \times [0,\,1]$, with $u(0,\,1) = 0$.

Replacing $u$ with $u - \frac{\epsilon}{4n}t(|x|^2-1) - \frac{\epsilon}{8n}$ we may assume that $(\partial_t - \Delta)u < 0$, with $u \leq -\epsilon / 8n$ on $(B_1 \times \{0\}) \cup (\partial B_1 \times [0,1])$ and $u(0,1) = \epsilon / 8n$. However, by the maximum principle, on the cylinders $\overline{B_1} \times [0,1-\delta]$, $u$ achieves its maximum on the sides or bottom, so $u \leq 0$ on all such cylinders. Taking $\delta \rightarrow 0$ we get a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, the basic idea is that you can modify the function so that to force the sides and bottom to be strictly smaller than the max. Then you can "slice off" the top and apply the differentiable version. (I prefer not to use the max principle since this exercise is a step in proving the maximum principle.)

Answer (score 3):

A potential-theoretic argument seems to be applicable. I come from probability, so I use the language of probabilistic potential theory below. However, everything can be translated into the language of harmonic (or ``caloric'') measures.

Let $X_t$ be the standard Brownian motion, generated by the Laplacian $\Delta$, and let $\mathbb{E}^x$ be the expectation corresponding to $X_0 = x$. For an open $D$ let $\tau_D$ be the time of first exit from $D$, and let $t \wedge s$ stand for the minimum of $t$ and $s$.

By standard arguments (Dynkin's formula or Itô's lemma, depending on where about in probability you come from), we have
$$ u(t,x) \leqslant \mathbb{E}^x(u(t - (\tau_U \wedge s), X_{\tau_U \wedge s}) - \varepsilon (\tau_U \wedge s)) $$
whenever $0 < s < t < T$ and $U \Subset \Omega$. By continuity, this estimate extends to $t = T$. If $u$ had a local maximum at $(T,x)$, we would have
$$ u(t,x) \geqslant \mathbb{E}^x u(t - (\tau_U \wedge s), X_{\tau_U \wedge s}) $$
if $s$ is sufficiently small and $U$ is a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $x$, contradicting the previous display. Thus, $u$ has no local minima in $(0, T] \times \Omega$.

Comment: Thanks! I chose Connor's answer because that is more easily explained to students in a first course in PDEs.

Comment: Sure thing! Both approaches are quite similar in the end, and it is always good to avoid probability, if possible.